# Read given file Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I try to read a certain file based on user TextBox input

Case:
There are 2 files: `A` and `B`. User types in "A" into `TextBox.Text` property and clicks a button to load the data from file.

File is processed by the JSONConverter and then displayed in UI.

Problem:
This works fine when `fileName` is hardcoded into function.
How do I make it read the `SearchBox.Text` property to look for a wanted file? If I use `string name = SearchBox.Text` and `string fileName = name + ".json"` it returns `The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.` - probably because I try to read from UI which is reserved for UI thread executed soon after? (I'm new and I try to understand the errors as well as possible).

```
 public async void DownloadDataAsync() 
        {
         // string fileName = SearchBox.Text; This doesn't work - it doesn't give compliation errors, 
            string fileName = "A.json"; // If this is set "hardcoded" the program executes correctly.
            StorageFile file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\HerodataJSON\" + fileName);
            string fileContent;
            using (StreamReader sRead = new StreamReader(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()))
            fileContent = await sRead.ReadToEndAsync();              

            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {                    
                Herodata hero = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Herodata>(fileContent);
                HeroName.Text = hero.Heroname;
                CounteredByList.Text = String.Join("\r\n", hero.Counteredby);
                CountersList.Text = String.Join("\r\n", hero.Counters);
                HeroPortrait.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(hero.IMGurl));
            });
        }

        private void BtnDownloadData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            Task t = new Task(DownloadDataAsync);
            t.Start();          
        }
```

Sidenote: this is going to be an application that displays "hero information" for one of the games, hence object naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access an UI element from a background thread. One quick fix is to read the value beforehand then pass it to your method:

```
private void BtnDownloadData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    var fileName = SearchBox.Text;
    Task t = new Task(() => DownloadDataAsync(fileName));
    t.Start();          
}
```

And change the signature of the other method to:

```
public async void DownloadDataAsync(string fileName)
```